# Controller does not recognize passed properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm creating a web api with ASP.NET Core and I've encountered a problem. I have a post request and I want to pass a Municipality object to it with JSON format. The problem is that I have property Name with attribute `[Required]`. I call the endpoint by using Postman with this JSON payload `{"Name": "London"}` and when validating the model, it says "The Name field is required." even though it was definitely provided.

I've tried using `[FromBody]` attribute, but the problem with it is that it doesn't give me validation errors and only says, that "input was invalid" and gives a null object, so not using this attribute gives a lot better errors.

Github: https://github.com/DeividasBrazenas/Taxes/blob/master/Taxes/Taxes/Controllers/BaseController.cs

**BaseModel.cs**

```
public class BaseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

**Municipality.cs**

```
public class Municipality : BaseModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tax> Taxes { get; set; }
}
```

**MunicipalitiesController.cs**

```
    [EnableQuery]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(Municipality baseObject)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        await Context.Set<Municipality>().AddAsync(baseObject);
        await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Created(baseObject);
    }
```

Screenshot of POST request - 
[image]

Comment: Is your `baseObject` getting filled with values in `Post(Municipality baseObject)` ?
provided by you from Postman? I mean you getting values to the `baseObject`?

Comment: How are you sending the data to the post action?

Comment: Kindly provide your postman call with json which you are passing with this call

Comment: I've added a link to screenshot to my question. Values are not getting filled in `baseObject` - they're null.

Comment: I don't know actual use of `EnableQuery` attribute, but try full object once. 
`{
 "Name": "London",
 "Id": 1,
 "Taxes": []
}`

Comment: @Hardik it is for OData. Just tried that, still the same, "The Name field is required."

Comment: I tried with `[FromBody]` and without body as well, it is working fine for me with same Model structure. Is breakpoint hitting your action method. did you check route is correct or not

Comment: Yes, breakpoint is being hit. That's weird if it works fine for you... I've added my github repo to the question. Maybe you could take a look?

Comment: @Deivyyyy, definately I will help you here as I am your ex-colleague .. I am ex-Bentley employee.. cheers

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar, hah! That's nice! xD

Comment: I tried your code and in first debug hit I noticed in your base controller in `baseobject` name is coming as a `null`, I will investigate more and will come up with solution

Comment: Thank you! Because I'm feeling really lost right now...

Comment: Does this really have something to deal with TaxesContext? I can get values into model when I use `[FromBody]` attribute

Comment: I tried by using `[FromBody]` attribute, this might be the solution for your problem, What is problem in using `[FromBody]` attribute

Comment: The problem with `[FromBody]` is that when something is wrong with JSON data (for instance, "name" starts not with a capital letter, like it is described in the model), it gives very abstract error message -  "The input was not valid.". I'd like to get more information about error.

Comment: `ModelState.AddModelError`?

Comment: @bolkay is that possible to create `ModelState.AddModelError` that would generically find what's wrong with the payload?

Comment: You'll have to define the errors yourself. I don't anyway to generically (or automatically if that's what you mean) generate error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make changes below for your current [MunicipalitiesController](https://github.com/DeividasBrazenas/Taxes/blob/master/Taxes/Taxes/Controllers/MunicipalitiesController.cs)

1. Add `public async Task<IActionResult> Post(Municipality baseObject)` with `FromBody`

   ```
   [EnableQuery]
   [HttpPost]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]Municipality baseObject)
   {
       if (!ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           return BadRequest(ModelState);
       }

       await Context.Set<Municipality>().AddAsync(baseObject);
       await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
       return Created(baseObject);
   }
   ```
2. Change the json request to lowercase.

   ```
   {
           "name":"1231"
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks!! You're a hero! xD